# How to execute JavaScript after a click of a button in other different frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

Imagine 2 frames in a page.

The 1st frame contains 3-4 buttons on left side of the page (navigation).
After clicking a button in 1st frame, the below JavaScript should get executed thus running the feed in the 2nd frame.

The requirement is that, page shouldn't reload after click of a button, button shouldn't disappear or change position after clicking.
The feed shouldn't run in a separate page. 
The resultant feed should run in a fixed area of 2nd frame irrespective of which button is clicked.

I've created a link to demonstrate what i've been able to do till now. [link] (indiangoggle.com/test1.php). please go through. As you can see the feed is appearing separately after reloading the page instead of loading in section 1 of the page.

```
    <!-- start feedwind code --><script type="text/javascript">document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://news.google.co.in/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss",rssmikle_frame_width: "400",rssmikle_frame_height: "500",frame_height_by_article: "0",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "on_mc",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "30",sort: "New",rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "Indian Latest News - As it happens",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "on",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script><div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:350px;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a><!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div><!-- end feedwind code -->
```

### Formatted:

```
<!-- start feedwind code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(
        '\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' +
        ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
        'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var params = {
            rssmikle_url: "http: //news.google.co.in/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss",
            rssmikle_frame_width: "400",
            rssmikle_frame_height: "500",
            frame_height_by_article: "0",
            rssmikle_target: "_blank",
            rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            rssmikle_font_size: "12",
            rssmikle_border: "off",
            responsive: "off",
            rssmikle_css_url: "",
            text_align: "left",
            text_align2: "left",
            corner: "off",
            scrollbar: "on",
            autoscroll: "on_mc",
            scrolldirection: "up",
            scrollstep: "3",
            mcspeed: "30",
            sort: "New",
            rssmikle_title: "on",
            rssmikle_title_sentence: "Indian Latest News - As it happens",
            rssmikle_title_link: "",
            rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
            rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
            rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
            rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
            rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
            rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
            rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",
            rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
            rssmikle_item_description: "on",
            item_link: "on",
            rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
            rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",
            rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",
            rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",
            datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",
            item_description_style: "text+tn",
            item_thumbnail: "full",
            item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",
            article_num: "15",
            rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",
            keyword_inc: "",
            keyword_exc: ""
        };
        feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);
    })();
</script>
<div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:350px;">
    <a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
    <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
</div>
<!-- end feedwind code -->
```

Comment: That's a lot of "should". What have you done so for to implement it? Does it work? If not, what *doesn't* work?

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle link of your complete HTML/JS file.

Comment: I don't like to imagine other people's problems, if you want us to help you show us the problem

Comment: Ok guys. I'll get back to all of u in few hours.

Comment: I've created a link to demonstrate what i've been able to do till now. [link] (http://indiangoggle.com/test1.php). please go through. As you can see the feed is appearing separately after reloading the page instead of loading in section 1 of the page.